# display html via JSTL in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have something like

```
model.addAttribute("msg", "<b>akhil</b>");
return "index";
```

in my Controller.

In my view page I wrote

```
<body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <c:out value="${msg}" />
</body>
```

But the output is `&lt;b>akhil&lt;/b>` as against `<b>akhil</b>.` Why is it so and what should be done to get `<b>akhil</b>`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is because `<c:out>` uses XML escaping for the characters `'<'` and `>`.

Set the option `escapeXml=false` of `c:out` to output your text in bold letters:

```
<c:out value="${msg}" escapeXml="false"/>
```